# How to detect the context menu opening over a WebView (Windows Store App)

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am trying to detect a long press/right click that opens the context menu over a WebView. I tried detecting a right click by using JavaScript (WebView.InvokeScript) however by capturing this right click it would also capture the right click to open the app bar.

I also took a look at customizing the context menu for a web view but it seems that this is not possible.

Is there a way detect a context menu opening up when the user is interacting with a WebView? Any help is appreciated, thanks!